# What is the dedicated html event for 'select' tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any dedicated event for select tag.

```
<select id="drp_fruits" class="field-select">
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

Comment: try onChange - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: try ... `onchange`

Comment: onchange event, see reference

Comment: `oninput` works with all form control elements, also `onchange` can be used with `select` element.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select - `change` and `input` This information is ***not*** hard to find.

Comment: What is the maximum negative vote a question can get? is there any limit?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I had already looked into link you have provided before submitting the question in stackoverflow. It is in `see also` section which I missed out somehow. My bad!

Comment: @Prem: I'm not aware of any limit. I've seen three digits worth here on SO (e.g., ~100 downvotes) and more on meta. :-)

Comment: No limits, but you're not even near to [the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=306766&sort=votes) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select onchange="myFunction()">
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

`change` is what are you looking for (as event listener).

```
var activities = document.getElementById("drp_fruits");

activities.addEventListener("change", () => {
    //do stuff)
})
```

Or :

```
<select id="drp_fruits" class="field-select" onchange="changeHandler()">
```

Tip: HTML **triggers** an event, but there are no such "html events". Events are handled by Javascript.

Comment: To be exact, althought JS handles the events, there are no JavaScript events, they are DOM events, hence "_html event_" is a valid term. Not my down vote, though.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wrote: HTML triggers events and JS handle them. And DOM !== HTML.

Comment: These are DOM events. HTML doesn't trigger events. User agents (such as browsers) trigger events in response to various situations (such as the user doing something, the user agent finishing building the DOM, etc.), and user agents handle events -- sometimes, if you've asked them to, they handle them in part by calling JavaScript code. If we want to be all pedantic and such. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Onclick its not good, use onchange function you got value

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```